# Need Help for Small Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coupon

how to create this type of code, if you click in get code button, you will redirect to another tab of the eCommerce store and coupon code will appear after you click on it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Html**

```
// use button 
<button onclick="Redirectpage()">Coupon Code</button>

// use Img 
<img src="" onclick="Redirectpage()"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Redirectpage() {
    location.href = "Put Your website here;
}
```

Comment: not working, maybe i am doing some mistake, can you provide me proper code, please i am not from technical field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<your new link here>" target="_blank" class="coupon_code">Coupon Code</a>
```

In your javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".coupon_code").click(function(){

       // place your javascript code for open popup of coupon code

       return true; // it will redirect to href link in new tab
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

`$('button').on('click',function()({`

```
   `$(this).html('your coupon code here');`
   ` window.open('https://link.com', '_blank');
```

`});`